# will there be any problems if referencing a library twice

Tags: c#, .net-core

So let's say you have project A which references library B and C. Library B itself references C too.

A real world example would be a Web API project with an Infrastructure and Application library. The API project references both of them and the Infrastructure layer references the Application layer too. This is because the Application layer defines multiple interfaces and the Infrastructure layer implements them. The Infrastructure layer needs to know about those Interface types.

[image]

I think the Application library gets loaded twice, no? Is it fine to do so or are there any other ways the Infrastructure layer can implement interfaces from the Application layer?

Comment: It is fine. And why do you think it would it be loaded twice?

Comment: I thought that A loads all the stuff from B and C while B already contains all the stuff from C

Comment: It won't. Otherwise if you have hierarchy like `proj1->proj2->proj3->proj4` and almost all of the project would be using `System` or `System.Data`, So it would get too much load if all those `System` libraries are loaded for each project. Definitely this thing are well managed by programmers.

Comment: You do sometimes see "found different versions of the same dependent assembly" and warnings indicating c# couldn't choose between two different versioned references. Read up about binding redirects etc